# Java Hosting options in the market

Tags: jboss, hosting, glassfish, application-server, geronimo

What are the best Java hosting you know working with appservers like glassfish, geronimo or jboss..

I've developed an application in glassfish, now its time to take that app online...

Based on your experience what hosting sellers/managers can you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For GlassFish, there is a dedicated page in the FAQ:

> #### [Which hosting providers support GlassFish?](http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=FaqGlassFishHosting)
>
> Hosting providers are a popular way of
>   deploying applications for
>   individuals, startups or even
>   well-established companies. Below is a
>   (growing) list of hosting providers
>   that currently support GlassFish.
>
> - [Dedicated Sun Servers](http://www.dedicatedsunservers.com/)
> - [eApps](http://www.eapps.com/)
> - [Web hosting](http://webspacehosting.com/) Glassfish wiki resource
> - [PLAVEB - Web Design Company](http://www.plaveb.com/)
> - [Entic.net](http://entic.net/servers)
> - [Gangus Internet Services LLC](http://www.gangusinternet.com/Landing/Solaris10Hosting.xhtml)
> - [Joyent](http://www.joyent.com/) ([Technical Specifications](http://www.joyent.com/accelerator/technical-specifications/))
> - [WebAppCabaret](http://www.webappcabaret.com/)
> - [1stRentalServer](http://java.1strentalserver.com/) - Japanese
>
> Also, see the [GlassFish Technology
>   Partner Showcase](http://www.sun.com/software/products/appsrvr/gf-si-partners.jsp) page for more
>   details.

#### See also

- [Thread: Shared Glassfish Hosting?](http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=102564)

Answer (score 4):

There's also the option of using Amazon EC2 and hosting the server yourself.  Depending on your usage, this may be a cheaper route to take.  You get full control over the OS, App Server, database, etc. that you use.  The downside is, you get full control over the OS, App Server, database, etc. that you use.  :)  In other words, you're on the hook for a lot of the administration and monitoring of your infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

To host your own Java Application Server the best way might be to hire a VPS (Virtual Privat Server) and istall your prefered AppServer on it.

An other option is to use Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using a debian-based VPS and hosting through RIMUHosting. I've gone through several VPS providers (VPSLink and such) and they have all been terrible as far as uptime and provide no support (as advertised). I've also gone the shared hosting route and have been dissatisfied with the level of access, quality, uptime, and service.

RIMU has phenomenal service. They are not a managed VPS per-se, but they sure do act like one. They helped me configure Tomcat as a service, they helped tweak Apache, they installed my JVMs for me, and they helped me set up Varnish cache. They also have a lot of people who host Java with them, so they know a lot about setting up standard Java architectures and front-loading with Apache.

The great thing is that they always respond quickly no matter what time of day you e-mail them. Even when they change shifts, the new support person picks up right where the last one left off.

I'm going on and on, but I've been truly impressed with their knowledge on Java and their level of support, at pretty much the same price as any other VPS.